# Count elements in a org-mode table

Tags: org-mode

NOI have an org-mode table with forth column containing only the words `YES` or `NO`

I would like to count how many `No`s  I have. 
I have little experience with calc, so from googling I got the following try:

```
#+TBLFM: @>$4=vcount(map(<if(eq($4,'NO'), 1, [])>, @I..@II))
```

which does not work. Thank for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no experience with calc, so I will use lisp instead (I am not skilled either though). I think this should work:

```
#+TBLFM: @>$4='(apply '+ (mapcar (lambda (x) (if (string= "YES" x) 1 0)) '(@I$4..@II$4)))
```

Regarding your function, try to quote `"$4"` and use the `string` function `eq("$4",string("NO")` cf [orgmode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html#Formula-syntax-for-Calc)

Hope it helps.

Comment: That worked for me. Your hint to my posted solution didn't work.